# Find out field in concern regarding FRAMEWORK__WRITE_MALFORMED_INPUT in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

Is there a way to find out which field is malformed?

Considering a large constructed array with a lot of data, this message is kinda useless:

```
{
  "errors": [{
            "status": "400",
            "code": "FRAMEWORK__WRITE_MALFORMED_INPUT",
            "title": "Bad Request",
            "detail": "Expected data to be array.",
            "meta": {
                "parameters": []
            },
            "trace": [{
                        "file": "\/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/shopware\/core\/Framework\/DataAbstractionLayer\/Write\/WriteCommandExtractor.php"
                        ....
```

The object I'm `POST`ing to `/api/product`:

```
{
    "productNumber": "00000158",
    "stock": 998,
    "price": [
        {
            "net": 5.2857,
            "gross": 6.29,
            "linked": true,
            "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca"
        }
    ],
    "taxId": "0189d01a0a0c73d98d9be2f6e4a4ad0b",
    "manufacturer": {
        "name": "Test Product Manufacturer"
    },
    "manufacturerNumber": null,
    "active": true,
    "shippingFree": false,
    "ean": "",
    "minPurchase": 1,
    "maxPurchase": null,
    "purchaseUnit": null,
    "weight": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "length": 0,
    "packUnit": null,
    "deliveryTime": null,
    "name": "Test Product",
    "keywords": null,
    "metaDescription": null,
    "metaTitle": null,
    "description": "",
    "releaseDate": null,
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-04 12:58:04",
    "createdAt": "2022-11-16 17:07:44"
}
```

I think it's not because of the manufacturer not being in an array, that triggers another exception:

```
...
"taxId": "0189d01a0a0c73d98d9be2f6e4a4ad0b",
"manufacturer": [
    {
        "name": "Test Product Manufacturer"
    }
],
...
```

> "status":"500","title":"Internal Server Error","detail":"Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Write\DataStack\KeyValuePair::__construct(): Argument #1 ($key) must be of type string, int given

I have then put the manufacturer via GUI into Shopware and it changes my POST query to the following, still throwing MALFORMED exception:

```
{
    "productNumber": "00000158",
    "stock": 998,
    "price": [
        {
            "net": 5.2857,
            "gross": 6.29,
            "linked": true,
            "currencyId": "b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca"
        }
    ],
    "taxId": "0189d01a0a0c73d98d9be2f6e4a4ad0b",
    "manufacturerId": "0189d56d52bf7356b43f09f511cda17d",
    "manufacturerNumber": null,
    "active": true,
    "shippingFree": false,
    "ean": "",
    "minPurchase": 1,
    "maxPurchase": null,
    "purchaseUnit": null,
    "weight": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "length": 0,
    "packUnit": null,
    "deliveryTime": null,
    "name": "Test Product",
    "keywords": null,
    "metaDescription": null,
    "metaTitle": null,
    "description": "",
    "releaseDate": null,
    "updatedAt": "2023-07-04 12:58:04",
    "createdAt": "2022-11-16 17:07:44"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the exception message should be more detailed. This exception is pretty much exclusively thrown when deserializing association type fields. For example you may have a `ManyToManyAssociationField` with the property name `categories`. When you want to assign categories, then your payload should look like this:

```json
{
  "id": "...",
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": "..."
    },
    {
      "id": "..."
    },
    {
      "id": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

However if your payload for the same property is written in the style of a `OneToOneAssociationField`, e.g. like this...

```json
{
  "id": "...",
  "categories": {
    "id": "..."
  }
}
```

...that's when that exception will be thrown. Even if you just want to assign a single category for instance, you'll have to provide an array of items, hence why the message reads `Expected data to be array`.

As already mentioned it's almost certainly going to be the partial payload of an association that is in an unexpected format. So check those first.

In your case you're setting `deliveryTime` to `null` but it is a property mapped by a `ManyToOneAssociationField` and as such must be at least an empty array or object.

Comment: Most of those fields are defined as `object` instead of `array<object>` in [the schema](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/1c10c832ff905-create-a-new-product-resources). It seems the schema is wrong there. In my case, can a product have several different manufacturers?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the schema is wrong on quite a few of those  However the value of the `manufacturer` property is mapped by a `ManyToOneAssociationField` and as such should be a single object. A product can only have one manufacturer assigned.

Comment: Do you spot anything in my product I want to push that is wrong?

Comment: In your case you're setting `deliveryTime` to `null` but it is a property mapped by a `ManyToOneAssociationField` and as such must be at least an empty array or object.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to set it, just remove the property from the payload entirely.

Comment: Fixing the `deliveryTime` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should inspect your data array first, you get this error for association fields.
So you need to check if you have for example "salutation" in your data array, you can't provide empty or invalid association fields.

Another solution would be debugging it, you could for example catch the Exception somewhere to get more information (e.g. in the WriteCommandExtractor class)

deliveryTime is a ManyToOneAssociationField, so NULL is not a valid value, you have to remove deliveryTime from your JSON object in order to not set one.

Comment: I put my data array in the question. Do you spot anything incorrect?

Comment: @DanielW. take a look at my updated answer.